# How to alert on increased "counter" value with 10 minutes alert interval

Tags: prometheus-alertmanager

So, I have monitoring on error log file(mtail). It's just count number of error lines. And mtail sums number of new lines in file.
I want to send alerts when new error(s) occured each 10 minutes only. Not for every single error.
Please, can you provide exact values for these lines:

```
    expr: increase(php_fpm_errors_total[10m]) > 0
    for: 10m
```

I would appreciate if you provide me some doc links or explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The way you have it, it will alert if you have new errors every time it evaluates (default=1m) for 10 minutes and then trigger an alert. There is also a property in alertmanager called group_wait (default=30s) which after the first triggered alert waits and groups all triggered alerts in the past time into 1 notification. You can remove the `for: 10m` and set group_wait=10m if you want to send notification even if you have 1 error but just don't want to have 1000 notifications for every single error